# Save the result of a CTE table into a volatile table

Tags: teradata, common-table-expression, volatile

I want to save the data from a CTE (Common Table Expression) into a volatile table in Teradata. In other words, I need to make the following simple syntax work (created as an example):

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE DATES (
   date_column DATE
) PRIMARY INDEX (date_column) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

WITH TEMP AS (
 SELECT calendar_date
 FROM sys_calendar.CALENDAR
 WHERE calendar_date BETWEEN DATE '2023-07-01' AND DATE '2023-07-31'
)
INSERT INTO DATES 
SELECT calendar_date
FROM TEMP;
```

The goal is to create a volatile table called DATES with a date_column as the primary index.

Comment: You define the CTE after the insert - `insert into dates with temp as(....) select  calendar_date from temp`